# How to Compare a empName and Value?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

Good morning,

Here is the situation:  Have a column of credit card transactions that lists  employee names and charge amounts a.k.a debits.  In the same column it also lists employee names with an equal negative amount which shows a credit to the account.

What I am trying to do is to find the employee name and charge amount.  Then cycle through the list and find the corresponding negative amount.

```
For example: 
John Doe, $100 
Jane Doe, $200 
Sam Smith, $300 
John Doe, -$100
```

When you run this module your results should return the names of Jane Doe and Sam Smith because only the records for John Doe had both a positive and negative value.

I have gotten very close to an answer but the solution falls apart when there are duplicate values.

```
For example: 

John Doe, $100 
John Doe, $100 
John Doe, -$100
```

In this solution the result should be John Doe, $100

So far I have tried with Access, VBA, and SQL but have not come up with an answer.

For the solution, I don't really care if it means adding another object such as a table or a query to perform the comparison part. In the end I need to see a list of matched and unmatched employee names and values.

Additionally, I thought about adding on a column to my table that has a Boolean logic to show the two "matched" records as this will be a database and we don't necessarily want to delete the matched rows from the table master.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really hard to do in MS Access (as are many things).  Can you switch to a more powerful database?

Comment: What is the business rule for matching when there are duplicate values?  This isn't an implementation question - it's a design question.

Comment: "When you run this module your results should return the names of Jane Doe and Sam Smith because only the records for John Doe had both a positive and negative value." - shouldn't "you" be "I" and "your" be "my"?

Comment: Gordon Linoff - No has to be done in Access with a query, SQL or VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Boolean field *Cleared*, and then run a simple loop in VBA to mark those set of record that match as cleared:

```
Public Function ClearTransactions()

    Dim db  As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Criteria As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From Transaction Where Value > 0 And Cleared = False Order By Id")
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From Transaction Where Value < 0 And Cleared = False Order By Id")

    While Not rs1.EOF
        Criteria = _
            "Id > " & rs1!Id.Value & " And " & _
            "EmpName = '" & rs1!EmpName.Value & "' And " & _
            "Value = " & Str(-rs1!Value.Value) & " And " & _
            "Cleared = False"
        rs2.FindFirst Criteria
        If rs2.NoMatch = False Then
            rs1.Edit
                rs1!Cleared.Value = True
            rs1.Update
            rs2.Edit
                rs2!Cleared.Value = True
            rs2.Update
        End If
        rs1.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs2.Close
    rs1.Close

    Set rs2 = Nothing
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table has a Primary Key (I'll call it `TransactionID` and assume it's Long Integer - adjust following code as necessary), in which case I would create a `tblMatches` with columns `DebitID` and `CreditID` to record pairs of entries that tie up. To populate this table:

```
Dim rsDebits As Recordset
Dim lngCreditID as Long

Set rsDebits = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("SELECT * FROM tblTransactions " & _
               "WHERE ChargeAmount > 0 And TransactionID Not In " & _
               "(SELECT DebitID From tblMatches)")

Do While Not rsDebits.EOF
    lngCreditID = Nz(DMin("TransactionID", "tblTransactions", _
                       "EmpName = '" & rsDebits!EmpName & "' And " _
                       "ChargeAmount = " & -rsDebits!ChargeAmount & " And " _
                       "TransactionID Not In (SELECT CreditID From tblMatches)"), 0)
    If lngCreditID > 0 Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblMatches (DebitID, CreditID) " & _
                          "VALUES (" & rsDebits!TransactionID & ", " & lngCreditID & ")"
    End If
    rsDebits.MoveNext
Loop

Set rsDebit = Nothing
```

You can now write a query joining this `tblMatches` to `tblTransactions` (twice, once joined `ON tblTransactions.TransactionID = tblMatches.DebitID` and the other one `ON tblTransactions.TransactionID = tblMatches.CreditID`) to show all the various entries that match up. To get a list of unmatched entries you'll need to design a query along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM tblTransactions
WHERE TransactionID Not In (Select DebitID From tblMatches)
    And TransactionID Not In (Select CreditID From tblMatches)
```